# Can't get RequestOptions params Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm extending the `Http` class from `@angular/http` to use custom a custom interceptor to set token headers and activate a loader when an HTTP Request is pending.

I'm trying to intercept a param sent by a GET method:

```
this.http.get('url', { params: { loader: 'customLoader' } })...
```

In my custom Http service:

```
request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
  options = this.resolveOptions(options);
  this.loaderService.show(this.resolveLoaderParam(options));
  return this.intercept(super.request(this.resolveUrl(url), options));
}
```

The `resolveOptions` just set the auth token.

The problem is that when I try to extract the params in the `RequestOptions`, in the `resolveLoaderParam`, it is `undefined` and the params are already written in the `URL`, like: `url?loader=customLoader`

---

**UPDATE**

```
private resolveOptions(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs {
  if (!options) {
    options = new RequestOptions();
  }

  if (!options.headers) {
    options.headers = new Headers();
  }

  options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  const headers = Object.keys(this.headers);

  if (headers.length > 0) {
    headers.forEach((item) => {
      options.headers.append(item, this.headers[item]);
    });
  }

  return options;
}
```

Comment: what does your resolveOptions(options) look like?

Comment: @deezg Updated the question

Comment: now i am not clear...are you trying to read param form url that you are already on or are you trying to read params from RequestOptios that will be used to build next url request?

Comment: I was trying to read the params in the `RequestOptions` in the `request` method, but as I'm using the `get` method, the url is already resolved when `request` is called. I'll have to use `RegExp` to catch the wanted param in the ´request´ method.

Comment: hm...that's strange. i have a similar scenario with interceptor and i can read my requestOptions normaly. it should have nothing to do with http verb. for example, this is how i read 'page' url parameter on get request: `options.search.get('page')`. `options.search` is of type `URLSearchParams` so you might want to look API for it.